# Publishing failures in Tridion/Web8.5 when more number of items are in queue(approx. 50-100 items at a time)

Tags: dxa, web8.5

When trying to publish 50-100 items at a time, publishing status remains in "Waiting for deployment" state and then fails after some time.
We have already allocated 16GB memory to deployer. Is this failure because of solr integration?. So, is there any fix for that?

Comment: Have you checked transport and/or deployer logs for any errors?

Comment: Provide more information and log details.

Comment: Also provide the information about your setup how many publishers and deployers how many threads configured in publisher and deployer?

Comment: I have provided the screenshot of deployer log. Please let me know if this would help you to provide the fix.

Comment: Solr client is receiving 404 errors from the Solr server.  I would check Solr server logs also.

Comment: Please make sure if the SOLR is accessible from deployer by directly hitting the SOLR URL from there? 404 states that deployer is not able to find SOLR.

Answer (score 2):

The failure is in the commit step. Usually this would mean that the deployer is unable to write the relevant records either to the file system (in which case, check your permissions) or to the database (possible issues with transactions).

In this case, though, I think you are right to suspect SOLR. The fact that a SOLR problem causes a Tridion storage exception makes me think someone has implemented a storage extension that needs to be correctly configured to find the SOLR server.

As that would be an issue with your implementation and not the product, your best bet is to seek information within your own organisation. Is there a technical design document that has the necessary information? Perhaps there's a code repository for the storage extension. Is there actually a server at stage-solr.carriercms.com, and if so who runs it (or should run it)?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and after a lot of brainstorming we noticed that the in deployer configurations (cd_storage_conf.xml), the **DefaultCoreUrl** is mentioned as:

```
<Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" DefaultCoreUrl="http://solrdomain.com:8083/solr/" DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt" Mode="http">
    <Urls>
        <Url Id="5" Value="http://solrdomain.com:8083/solr/examplesite"/>
    <Urls>
</Indexer>
```

Notice that it has no core specified in it. If you are trying to publish from a publication not specified in URL list in the configuration, it will publish to the the **DefaultCoreURL**.

To fix the issue add the publication id with proper SOLR URL or provide a proper **DefaultCoreURL** in the settings.